# Hazelcast Out of Memory

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

We have a Java app which processes 100k packages per minute. The packages include user operation details and for one user operation. There can be 3 to 14 packages for a operation. All received packages contain unique data for the operation and unfortunately the operation does not have an id. Because of that we are using user id and operation date to merge the packages which belong to the same operation. It is guaranteed to us that we will receive all the packages for a user operation in 15 minutes max. So to merge all the packages before persisting, we are caching all received packages on Hazelcast and insert the packages when OPSTART or OPEND packages are received. The packages expire at 20 minutes. However after running 1 hour or so, Hazelcast heap space exceeds 70%.

```
c.h.internal.diagnostics.HealthMonitor   : [192.168.2.42]:5701 [dev] [3.7.5] processors=4, physical.memory.total=15.7G, physical.memory.free=6.1G, swap.space.total=2.0G, swap.space.free=2.0G, heap.memory.used=3.1G, heap.memory.free=267.1M, heap.memory.total=3.3G, heap.memory.max=3.5G, heap.memory.used/total=92.15%, heap.memory.used/max=88.02%, minor.gc.count=71, minor.gc.time=4628ms, major.gc.count=10, major.gc.time=7186ms, load.process=0.00%, load.system=0.01%, load.systemAverage=0.00%, thread.count=502, thread.peakCount=502, cluster.timeDiff=-121091, event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=0, executor.q.client.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0, executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0, executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operations.size=0, executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, operations.completed.count=4722977, executor.q.mapLoad.size=0, executor.q.mapLoadAllKeys.size=0, executor.q.cluster.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0, operations.running.count=0, operations.pending.invocations.percentage=0.00%, operations.pending.invocations.count=50, proxy.count=0, clientEndpoint.count=0, connection.active.count=1, client.connection.count=0, connection.count=1
```

And after approximately 1 and a half an hour later invocations start to time out.

```
c.h.s.i.o.impl.InvocationMonitor         : [192.168.2.42]:5701 [dev] [3.7.5] Invocations:50 timeouts:0 backup-timeouts:1
```

After 2-3 hours from the start Hazelcast throws an out of memory exception and the deployment dies.

4GB of memory should be enough for the data that has been cached. We could not find what causes to Hazelcast to throw an out of memory exception. What could be the reason? What can we do to understand the problem?

Comment: How did you calculate the need, if you say 4GB should be enough? Did you look at a head dump yet?

Comment: It sounds like the "expire" process is not evicting packages. That, or some other kind of memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to determine the cause of the OOME is make a heapdump and analyze it and see how memory is retained. Probably it will be a huge number of byte arrays. If you check for the incoming references to these byte arrays and aggregate them (jprofiler has excellent support for this), it is very easy to determine the chain of classes retaining memory.